# Strange behavior of NSString

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a `NSString` that will be passed as a parameter to my library's function, the `NSString` is passed by another library. The strange thing is, if I pass the `NSString` to the library call, the call will fail, but if I convert the `NSString` to `int` and then convert the `int` back to a `NSString`, every thing is fine.

But by printing it out using `NSLog("%@")`, the two strings are identical. What may cause this? Encoding?

Comment: incorrect memory management would be my guess...

Comment: what do you mean by "the call will fail"?

Comment: Can you show some code? The non-working & the working version

Comment: Can you post some code? And also what do you mean by "fail"? Is there an error, or is the string nil?

Comment: Maybe the string contains non-alpha characters, removed by conversion to the integer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you

> convert the NSString to int and then convert the int back to a NSString

you are basically creating a copy of the string, unrelated to the original one.

It would be interesting to know how you create the two strings to know what exactly happens. My guess is that the first one is deallocated too soon, so the call fails; the copy is retained and the call succeeds.

Just for a quick try:

when calling the function that is failing:

```
[self doMethodWithString:aString];
```

just do:

```
[aString retain];
[self doMethodWithString:aString];
```

If this works, then the memory management issue is confirmed, but for a real fix you should explain how you create the strings...

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me besides using the covert-to-int-and-back method, can I copy a string (i mean deep copy) unrelated to the original one to avoid the memory issue?

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan: I don't think that casting back and forth can have any useful effect... so I take converting for what it should mean... Bin Chen: please, see my edit...

Comment: On a 64-bit system, it would truncate the pointer. More broadly speaking, it's just unsafe.

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan: I totally agree about the truncation. Still, I am not advocating that...

Comment: @BinChen what about the -copy method of NSString?

Comment: `copy` would give you a retained copy, so it would work all the same as retaining the original one. But I strongly suggest you understand *why* things do not work as you expect, otherwise you would likely end up with a leak... in other words: if you copy or retain, make sure it is also released at some point.